# Leitura de uma String

Tags: c, c++

Se eu tiver uma String que é:

```
String s = "2123dog";
```

Como posso calcular o primeiro caractere `2` para transformar os próximos 2 caracteres em um inteiro, e 4 para transformar o nome que é dog?

O resultado seria ( 12, dog )?

Comment: Além da pergunta não estar clara qual o objetivo e ela parece dizer uma coisa e a resposta aceita parece fazer outra, em qual linguagem está perguntando? Nem parece C ou C++, embora tecnicamente seria possível, mas altamente improvável.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei se entendi direito sua pergunta, mas talvez fosse algo assim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "2123dog";
    int n = stoi(s.substr(0, 1), NULL);
    int n2 = stoi(s.substr(1, n), NULL);
    int n3 = stoi(s.substr(1 + n, 2 + n), NULL);
    string resto = s.substr(2 + n);
    cout << n << " - " << n2 << " - " << n3 << " - " << resto;
    return 0;
}
```

A saída é: `2 - 12 - 3 - dog`. Observe que todos os três números foram armazenados em variáveis do tipo `int`.

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/oOblT3)